# JSON Lists not removing duplicates with Distinct command

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

Currently I am querying a web service that returns a JSON string.

```
url = @"redacted url;
returnValue = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
```

I am putting the return results into a list of items defined in a model class. I am then running a second JSON call searching a different field with that same search term.

```
url2 = @"redacted url2;
returnValue2 = new WebClient().DownloadString(url2);
```

I then create my lists and combine the lists using AddRange.

```
List<Order> shipments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(returnValue);
List<Order> shipments2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(returnValue2);
shipments.AddRange(shipments2);
```

As a result there are some duplicates. To try and only return unique records I am using the command Distinct when sending to my MVC view from the controller.

```
return View(shipments.OrderBy(x => x.dtDateReceived).Distinct().ToList());
```

But for some reason it's still returning duplicates.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `Order` has many properties. What makes an object unique when it gets compared to another ? You need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` where you can compare the OrderId value. See this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up correcting it using Shyju's comment above.
I changed the Distinct to the following.

```
return View(shipments.OrderBy(x => x.dtDateReceived).Distinct(new OrderComparer()).ToList());
```

Then built the following compare functions

```
// Custom comparer for the Order class
    class OrderComparer : IEqualityComparer<Order>
    {
        // Orders are equal if their names and order numbers are equal.
        public bool Equals(Order x, Order y)
        {

            //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

            //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            //Check whether the order's properties are equal.
            return x.sWorkOrderNumber == y.sWorkOrderNumber && x.sCustomerOrderName == y.sCustomerOrderName;
        }

        // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
        // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

        public int GetHashCode(Order order)
        {
            //Check whether the object is null
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(order, null)) return 0;

            //Get hash code for the sCustomerOrderName field if it is not null.
            int hashOrderName = order.sCustomerOrderName == null ? 0 : order.sCustomerOrderName.GetHashCode();

            //Get hash code for the sWorkOrderNumber field.
            int hashOrderCode = order.sWorkOrderNumber.GetHashCode();

            //Calculate the hash code for the order.
            return hashOrderName ^ hashOrderCode;
        }
    }
```